# Cannot install font

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2012, fonts

When I try to run the following code segment in VS2012, it installs the font as expected.  However when I start to app from Windows Explorer, it returns the following error: "Unable to install needed font: The system cannot find the file specified"

```
    class Program
{
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "AddFontResourceW", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int AddFontResource([In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
                                     string lpFileName);
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string spath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\\lucon.ttf";
        int result = AddFontResource(spath);
        int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        if (error != 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unable to install needed font: "+ new Win32Exception(error).Message);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine((result == 0) ? "Font is already installed." : "Font installed successfully.");
        }
    }
}
```

The lucon.ttf is in the correct folder.  Can someone please explain this and help me to get it running when the console app is started from Windows Explorer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error handling is broken.  Windows in general does **not** reset the last error when the function doesn't fail.  Furthermore, AddFontResource() is special in that it does *not* set the last error at all, check the MSDN article.  Otherwise common behavior for GDI functions.  So you must do it like this:

```
    int result = AddFontResource(spath);
    if (result == 0) {
        Console.WriteLine("Unable to install needed font");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Might as well fix the pinvoke declaration:

```
   [DllImport("gdi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
   public static extern int AddFontResource(string lpFileName);
```